# Header fixed by css position:fixed and lightbox effect get overlayed by it

Tags: css, slider, lightbox, fixed

I got a problem of images and header and a lightbox effect. Actually in my website I needed the header as a constant so I made it constant by adding css property *position:fixed* and it worked out also but I got another problem as this messed up with lightbox effect. It got underlayed by header. I want that when I open lightbox the header should be overlayed by lightbox effect. And again a problem of images that I put in the slider when scrolls are also giving problems.

Please check this site **http://www.sultanindustries.in** and scroll to our portfolio and open one of image and scroll to top you will clearly understand my problem.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here on StackOverflow.

Comment: have you seen problem live? i will post code for that...

Comment: sites change in time, that is why is good to have here a set of code to work with. Also you can show what you have tried so far and did not worked.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the z-index of the header to be less than the z-index of the lightbox. I couldn't replicate the problem on your site so maybe you've solved it already.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey guys i found the answer. Thank u [kayee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1513558/kayee). That problem caused due to Z-index. I have changed Z-index property.

Things that i had to keep on top, i have increased their z-index.

```
z-index:999; //for lightbox popup
```

for other

```
Z-index:900; //less than lightbox popup z-index
```

and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use this much of z-index

```
z-index:15; //for lightbox popup for other

Z-index:10; //less than lightbox popup z-index
```

if you will use that much of z-index it may affect other lightbox effects.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the problem of z-index.
Please check the value of z-index on page and please update the code in question so that you can have better answer.

thank you